# My Cloudflare site is taking hours to load CSS

Tags: css, frontend, cloudflare

I created a domain on CloudFlare, a website with HTML and CSS, hosted my bucket with those files on S3, and integrated terraform for deployments. When I kick off terraform apply and run the aws cli command to update the S3 bucket, formatting changes like text show immediately but my CSS changes like font sizes and colors take several hours to be visible. How can I make both types of changes visible quickly?

I tried hard reloading my browser, clearing cache, and setting auto minify on cloudflare. I haven't tried gzipping my css and min.css files, a little afraid I might break something. I'm unfamiliar with front end development. Suggestions?

Comment: This is definitely a cache issue. Check your cloudflare settings to clear the cache there. You can test by using a cache busting query string, e.g., www.yourdomain.com?cache_bust=1234 or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proxied ("orange clouded") DNS record, Cloudflare applies a default caching behaviour. This includes default cached file extensions such as CSS files. The default behaviour, caching and extensions cached are [documented here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior).

When you do a release on your origin (S3 bucket), you could [purge the cache](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/purge-cache) so that the old cached versions are discarded and new ones will be pulled and cached. You can also override the cache behaviour by using [Page Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/create-page-rules). By the way, Page Rules (and other Cloudflare settings) are also [manageable via Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/page_rule).

Comment: I don't know how I missed it but under Caching-> configuration-> browser caching TTL was automatically set to 4 hours

Comment: Just keep in mind that you have browser caching and edge caching as well, the 2nd is the time the resource is stored on the Cloudflare servers.